Event thet work on Legacy Outlook For Mac
Is there any event work with legacy outlook for mac?
OnNewMessageCompose //Work When Mail Composed

OnNewMessageCompose work with new oulook but dont work with legacy outlook.
Any event would work except ItemSend but i would prefer OnNewMessage.
